# Forcing MS Word 15 (mac) to ignore patterns with square [b]rackets while spell-checking

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, spell-check

The common approach to changing quotation involves using **`[ ]`**. For instance, the original sentence:

> Reading is also a process and it also changes (...)

could be altered in the following manner when quoted:

> Margaret Atwood wants her readers to realize that "**`[r]eading`** is also a
>   process and it also changes `[them]`".

*[Source: University of Washington](https://depts.washington.edu/engl/askbetty/changing_quotations.php)*

## Problem

This proves immensely difficult for MS Word to handle, as demonstrated below:

[image: Ms Word error]

When faced with:

```
[r]eaders
  ^^^^^^^
```

MS Word will highlight second part of the word as a potential error. Is it possible to change this behaviour and force MS word to ignore strings of format **[s]tring**?

---

## Side points

- I would like to avoid adding odd strings to the custom dictionary as, with time, this will create awful mess with a vast number of words having *[a]lternative* spelling saved.